# DataType for Saving Images in DataColumn of DataTable

Tags: c#, datagridview, datatable, datagridviewcolumn, datacolumn

I have a seemingly simple problem, I have created a DataTable dynamically and I add rows to it just fine. However I have a column that will have a flag which is an image. I had already imported the two flags(.png images) into the projects resources. However I cant set the DataType for the column as System.Type.Bitmap as DataColumn doesnt support that as can be seen here  HERE . I had seen a solution that said I set DataType as below

```
dataColumn = new DataColumn("Flag");
dataColumn.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Byte[]"); //Replacing System.Byte[] with System.Type.Bitmap throws Type Exception
dataTable.Columns.Add(dataColumn);
```

However that throws an Exception stating that compiler expected Byte[] but got Bitmap.

Here is how I add rows to DataTable

```
row["Part Number"] = part;
row["Module Name"] = populator.LookUpAValue(moduleSql);
row["Flag"] = Properties.Resources.Yellow_Flag;
row["Location"] = populator.LookUpAValue(nameSql);
dataTable.Rows.Add(row);
```

Here is my question, which DataType do I save the image column as so when I display to a DataGridView I see the images displayed. Without setting DataType on the DataGridView instead of images being displayed, I get text
`System.Drawing.Bitmap`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the code that worked for me.

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
DataColumn dc = new DataColumn("Column1");
dc.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Byte[]");
dt.Columns.Add(dc);
DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
var imageConverter = new ImageConverter();
row["Column1"] = imageConverter.ConvertTo(Properties.Resources._1, System.Type.GetType("System.Byte[]")); 
dt.Rows.Add(row);
this.dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use `Bitmap` or `Byte[]` as `DataType`.

`DataGridView` displays the type name if you have associated the `DataColumn` with the `DataGridViewTextColumn` instead of `DataGridViewImageColumn`. Add a `DataGridViewImageColumn` and associate the image column in the `DataTable` to this created column.

If you want to set the `DataType` as `Byte[]`, when storing the image, you have to covert the image to `Byte[]` and while reading from the `DataTable` covert from `Byte[]` to image.

```
dataColumn.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Byte[]");
```

Image to `Byte[]` conversion

```
Image image = dataGridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[columnIndex].Value as Image;
if(image != null)
{
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    image.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.);
    byte[] imagedata = ms.ToArray();
}
```

`Byte[]` to image conversion

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imagedata);
Image img = Image.FromStream(ms);
dataGridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[columnIndex].Value = img;
```